# Can't install Google Earth plugin in Chrome on OSX

Tags: google-chrome, google-earth, browser-plugin

This is weird.  A few months ago I had the plugin running just fine in Chrome.  Now it's not showing up (OSX 10.9.5, Chrome Version 40.0.2214.111 (64-bit)).

When I go to http://www.google.com/intl/en/earth/explore/products/plugin.html I see the [Download the Google Earth Plugin] button.  When I click, download and open dmg file I get the "Google Earth Web Plug-in" and double click that.  I see it run the process and say 'Copying "Google Earth Web Plug-in.plugin" to "Internet Plug-Ins"'.  But when I look in "/Library/Internet Plug-Ins", there is no Google anything.  And when I restart Chrome and go back to http://www.google.com/intl/en/earth/explore/products/plugin.html I still see the [Download the Google Earth Plugin].

Weirdly enough however the plugin is working in Safari and Firefox.

Comment: Have you re-installed chrome? Or at least cleared the cache. What about trying an older version of chrome?

Comment: @jlarson Did you solve the issue? I am also having the same issue.

Comment: Nope.  However, I also found out that Google is deprecating the Google Earth Plugin at the end of 2015 (http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com/2014/12/announcing-deprecation-of-google-earth.html), which completely kills the reason I was trying to use it.... : (

Answer (score -1):

Do you use the 64-Bit version of Chrome? If yes, then [this](http://www.gearthblog.com/blog/archives/2014/09/64-bit-chrome-drops-support-google-earth-plugin.html) could answer your question.

Essentially the google earth plugin is based off NPAPI and 64 bit google earth has dropped support for the 32 bit NPAPI plugin format. You'll need to use earth mode from google maps, which is somewhat limited.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. External links can break or be unavailable, in which case your answer would not be useful.  Please include the essential information within your answer and use the link for attribution and further reading.  Thanks.